# Django separate permissions for get and post method in generic view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created generic views in django rest framework which allows listing and creation of objects to admin user. But, what I am really trying to achieve is any user staff status should be able to get the objects (use get method) but only super user should be able to create objects (use post method). Here are my generic views.

```
class StateList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = State.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `get_permission` for that.

```py
class StateList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = State.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]


    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
        return [AllowAny()]
```